# Django filter when value none or not or certain value

Tags: django

I want to filter my model values. I have three fields. This fields can be `null` or  `None` or certain value. How to prevent filter error when value null or not:

```
queryset = info.objects.filter(tag_id=tag.objects.get(pk=tag_id), entryDate__gte=startDate, exitDate__lte=endDate)
```

This is my model:

```
class info (models.Model):

    tag = models.ForeignKey(equipment_models.tag, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    entryDate = models.DateTimeField()
    exitDate = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __int__(self):
```

I got Cannot use None as a query value when any of tag_id, startDate or endDate is None.

Comment: what is the error you receive?

Comment: `NULL` and `None` are the same, unless it is a charfield where you store `'null'` *as* string.

Comment: Can you share your relevant models?

Comment: Also `tag_id=tag_id` should suffice, no need to nest a query.

Comment: "_How to prevent filter error when value null or not_", what exactly do you mean by this statement? If you are getting an error, please _add_ ([edit]) it to your question. Also what exactly is `None`? Is it the variables `startDate`, etc?

Comment: `blank=True` does *not* mean that you can store whitespace or an empty string in the field, it basically means that it is *not* a *required* field for `ModelForm`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with a `Q` object to retrieve the `Info` object if exitDate is `NULL`, or less than or equal to `endDate`. We can also optimize the search by filtering on the `tag_id`, instead of first making a query to fetch the tag.

Furthermore we can construct a `Q` object that only adds conditions if the corresponding values are not `None`:

```
from django.db.models import Q

my_q = Q()
if endDate is not None:
    my_q = Q(exitDate__lte=endDate)
if tag_id is not None:
    my_q &= Q(tag_id=tag_id)
if startDate is not None:
    my_q &= Q(entryDate__gte=startDate)

queryset = Info.objects.filter(
    my_q
)
```

Comment: I got ValueError("Cannot use None as a query value"). When any of tag_id, startDate or endDate is None.

Comment: @uyarc: ah, but the nullables are not the fields, but the values for which you filter. Then you thus perform a check if the items are `None`.

Comment: Thanks a lot ı checked it but ı can not use Q object.